# encoding field as geo_point while writing DStream to Elastic search

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, kibana, geopoints

I am writing **JavaDStream** 
containing objects of type Tweet from spark to elastic search using method **JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveToEs**. Below is the definition of my Tweet class.

```
public class Tweet implements Serializable{

String longitude;
String latitude;
String sentiment;
String text;
String post_date;
String geo_point;
```

In geo_point I am appending longitude, latitude.

When I am writing this DStream to ES, type of field geo_point is showing as text and I am not able to use it on Kibana to visualize data on Geographic Map. I have set es.index.auto.create = true. How to convert the type of that field to geo_point so that it can be used on Kibana Map?

Comment: You've defined your index types correctly? `Tweet` is a JavaBean? How does your `geo_point` string look? Please provide much more information.

Answer (score 1):

Its solved now. Created index before dumping data in ES using java code and marked field type as geo_point. Then started dumping data in ES. Now I can use that field for map as type is geo_point.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer :

Elasticsearch data type mapping can not be applied on existing indexes . we should create ES templates before ingesting data for that particular index.

Index templates :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Define Geo Type for Kibana :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/geo-point.html

Comment: Tried same thing. Still its type shows as string and not able to use it in map. Then I tried creating new index from java code before writing data elastic search and in that index marked geo_point field with type geo_point. Then started dumping data ES. Its working now.

Comment: Once an index is created , we can not change mapping for the existing fields . Best practice is to create templates before start ingesting data into elasticsearch. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: Sindhu: Thanks for the input. Followed same.